# partial class does not contain definition

Tags: c#, class, partial

I got a weird problem and finally fixed it. Just like to share this expeirence so other people will search this topic and get the answer.
I defined 2 partial classes, and compiled with the error of "does not contain a definition for ...". It was weird because it worked when the 2 classes were individual classes.

Here is the code:

Before:
Foo1.cs

```
public class foo1{public void xyz(){}}
```

Foo2.cs

```
public class foo2{}
```

After:
Foo1.cs

```
public partial class foo1{  public void xyz(){}}
```

Foo2.cs

```
public partial class foo1{}
```

Compilation said "MyNamespace.foo1 does not contain a definition for xyz". But xyz was good when the class was not partial! This could be caused by different namespaces. But I doubted that. Because if namespaces were different, it would not compile.

I figured out at last. The problem was in Foo1.cs, the namespace was not defined but it was defined in Foo2.cs. Before I defined the partial class, the compiler provided a default namespace to Foo1.cs, that was the same as the one defined explicitly in Foo2.cs. But with the partial class, the compiler would not provide a default namespace to the partial class. This is why the compiler complained when a third party called foo1.xyz().

I learned a lesson that always define the namespace explicitly for each single cs file, except that you do not define the namespace.

Comment: So the question is closed, right ?

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer to your own question, and accept that answer by clicking the check-mark next to it. Otherwise, this question will appear to be unanswered by other visitors to the site. Thanks.

Comment: (Removed my other comment.) The lesson to learn is that if you want to merge to distinct classes into one single class, using `partial` declarations, then both parts must be in the same namespace. If no explicit namespace is given, a type belongs to the global namespace.

Comment: I just like to share this experience. Before I fixed my problem, I did not get answers at this site.

Comment: @user1807086: As stated by Dan J, [please share the experience in a *question + answer* format](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), not in a *question whose text somewhere contains the answer* format.

Comment: This is my first time I post my exeriences. I learned a lot from others. I am not familiar with the "how to" here. I tried to close this question but the system ask me to wait for a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Always define namespace explicitly.